# Nginx, uwsgi and flask does not display the css file

Tags: python, css, nginx, flask

I have set up  uwsgi and nginx to serve a flask website that I'm working on but it refuses to display the css file even though it appears in the body of the page correctly and I can view it. It does not change the styling of the page.

I use the following nginx.conf

```
worker_processes 1;

events {

    worker_connections 1024;

}

http {

    sendfile on;

    gzip              on;
    gzip_http_version 1.0;
    gzip_proxied      any;
    gzip_min_length   500;
    gzip_disable      "MSIE [1-6]\.";
    gzip_types        text/plain text/xml text/css
                      text/comma-separated-values
                      text/javascript
                      application/x-javascript
                      application/atom+xml;

    # Configuration containing list of application servers
    upstream uwsgicluster {

    server 127.0.0.1:8080;
    # server 127.0.0.1:8081;
    # ..
    # .

}

# Configuration for Nginx
server {

    # Running port
    listen 80;

    # Settings to by-pass for static files 
    location ^~ /static/  {

        # Example:
        # root /full/path/to/application/static/file/dir;
        root /app/static/;

    }

    # Serve a static file (ex. favico) outside static dir.
    location = /favico.ico  {

        root /app/favico.ico;

    }

    # Proxying connections to application servers
    location / {

        include            uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass         uwsgicluster;

        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;

    }
}
}
```

Comment: In you access log what does it say is being requested by the user? It may be that /static/static/ is what is being requested

Comment: Ah sorry I just copied that from source but I'd already changed that bit. It definitely can find the file. When I go to the source of the html via the browser I can click on the css file and it shows me the source it just doesn't use it to display on the page.

Comment: This is why I was asking what is being requested in the access.log file. If you are going to the same /static/ in the HTML page it may be a miss config with the `url_for`

Comment: http://pastebin.com/KrWSqhEn

Access.log file.

Comment: If you visit example.com/static/css/pure-min.css then it works?

Comment: Yeah, just displays the text but I just noticed that I can do that even if uwsgi isn't running.

Comment: Strange... its you can hit that address from the outside there should be no reason you can't when the Flask app includes it, if that is the exact address the Flask application is requesting in the <link> tag then I am stumped.

Comment: if you can see the css file link in the html source of the page, and when you click on it , it shows you the css file. Then I think from an nginx / flask perspective, everything is fine. There is probably a bug in your html or css. Maybe post a link to a fiddle illustrating the problem

Comment: Apparently it was something to do with a combination of caching and the static serving of nginx not working. It is resolved now though.

Comment: How did you solve it ?